# Custom GcmListenerService not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="be.customapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM: keep device awake while receiving a notification -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <!-- GCM: receive push notifications -->
    <permission android:name="be.customapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="be.customapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- Meta data -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

        <!-- Activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Services -->
        <service
            android:exported="false"
            android:name=".services.gcm.MyGcmListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:exported="false"
            android:name=".services.gcm.GcmRegisterService"/>
        <service
            android:name=".services.gcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <!-- Broadcastreceivers -->        
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="be.prior_it.evapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the service that gets/registers my registration id;

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token =      instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

MyGcmListenerService;

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        super.onMessageReceived(from, data);
        Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Got GCM message " + data.getString("message"));
    }
}
```

The server uses PushJack and sends to the registration id's. I can see that the server can send the messages, I can get my registration id and register it with our server, but the onMessageReceived never gets called... I also made the google-services.json using the link on the website, so that should also be okay.

Any or all ideas are welcome.

Comment: Did you subscribe to a topic that your notification send? Or are you sending to your specific device Token? The code above has too little info (e.g. what's your function header of getting the registration id? How's your GCMListenerServices written?

Comment: The server is sending to the specific token that was sent to it in the service that registers the device with the GCM. The Gcm listener now only logs the Bundle if the function gets ever called, which never happens. What do you mean by the function header used for getting the reg id?

Comment: Did you have your internet permission turned on? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your manifest, what about posting your code for MyGcmListenerService

Comment: Added it... Thanks for the help

Comment: No worries, that looks all good too. Are you sure you generated the configuration file correctly and put it in the right place in your app? Sorry i know this might be a simple thing but it just helps narrow it down

Comment: I didn't have it at first, and it asked me for it. I then generated it, and verified that the server key and the project id are the same as used by the server. It's also using the correct json file, because it can generate the string needed for token retrieval. And no problem man, any help with this is very welcome...

Comment: Where is it placed in your project? Alongside you app/bulid.gradle file?

Comment: Yes. I took this project back home, and it appears to be working now. For some reason the GCM messages for that specific project were being blocked at work... I have no clue how that is even possible...

Comment: haha glad to hear you've got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your permissions.